# With login call in constructor, when to call logout?

Tags: c#, idisposable

I have a class that wraps an API. The methods are all API calls. In the constructor it logs in to the API and stores a session token as part of the private class data. All the actual API calls then use that token to make the individual calls.

The API also has a logout call that more or less ends the session. My question is where should I do the logout call? Something with a finalizer? I'm currently using some sort of simple IDisposable implementation but that doesn't really feel like it's the best/proper way.

Comment: If it were me, I would provide explicit login/logout methods on my own versions of the class, because typically you want tight control over that kind of stuff. Of course, I don't know your use case, so voted to close because it's an opinion thing without any concrete details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your object should implement `IDisposable` and you should call logout in your `Dispose` method because this is the expected way to deal with non-memory related resources in .Net.